# Feature Class still has deleted field names when I use arcpy.Describe or arcpy.ListFields

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, feature-class

I've got a Python script that "cleans up" a feature class by renaming fields to something more legible -- add a new field (e.g. "DistrictName"), copy data from old field (e.g. "DISTNAM") to new field, and delete the old field. This is done for a lot of fields, so I built functions:

```
def delete_field(tbl, fieldName):
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(tbl, fieldName)
def replace_field(tbl, newFieldName, oldFieldName, dataType):
    arcpy.AddField_management(tbl, newFieldName, dataType)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(tbl, [newFieldName, oldFieldName]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0] = row[1]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
    delete_field(tbl, oldFieldName)
```

But there's a subsequent step in the Python script that is exporting this feature class to an Excel spreadsheet, and part of the process builds a list of the fields to be used to create a header row of column names.

```
data_description = arcpy.Describe(dataset_name)
fieldnames = [f.name for f in data_description.fields if f.type not in ["Geometry", "Raster", "Blob"]]
```

When I look at the resulting feature class in ArcMap, all the old field names have been deleted, which is exactly what I would expect. When Python does that `Describe` step, it sees both the new AND the old field names -- but it breaks when attempting to copy an old field, since the data does not actually exist.

What step can I add between deleting and listing to "update" the feature class `fields` so it only lists the existing fields, and not any fields which were recently deleted?

---

EDIT: I pulled the `Describe` portion out of its function and put it directly after the sequence of `replace_field` operations. Also tried using `arcpy.ListFields` instead of the `Describe` method.

```
replace_field(tableName, "District_Name", "DISTRICTNAME", "TEXT")
replace_field(tableName, "District_Number", "DISTRICT", "LONG")
replace_field(tableName, "LocalOffice_Name", "LOCALOFFICENAME", "TEXT")
replace_field(tableName, "Substation_Number", "SUBSTATIONID", "LONG")
replace_field(tableName, "FeederID", "CIRCUITID", "LONG")
replace_field(tableName, "OH_SinglePhase_CircuitMiles", "OH_SINGLEPHASE", "DOUBLE")
replace_field(tableName, "OH_TwoPhase_CircuitMiles", "OH_TWOPHASE", "DOUBLE")
replace_field(tableName, "OH_ThreePhase_CircuitMiles", "OH_THREEPHASE", "DOUBLE")
replace_field(tableName, "OH_Total_CircuitMiles", "OH_TOTALCIR", "DOUBLE")
replace_field(tableName, "UG_SinglePhase_CircuitMiles", "UG_SINGLEPHASE", "DOUBLE")
replace_field(tableName, "UG_TwoPhase_CircuitMiles", "UG_TWOPHASE", "DOUBLE")
replace_field(tableName, "UG_ThreePhase_CircuitMiles", "UG_THREEPHASE", "DOUBLE")
replace_field(tableName, "UG_Total_CircuitMiles", "UG_TOTALCIR", "DOUBLE")

data_description = arcpy.Describe(tableName)
fieldnames = [f.name for f in data_description.fields if f.type not in ["Geometry", "Raster", "Blob"]]
print fieldnames

apyListFields = arcpy.ListFields(tableName)
print apyListFields
```

The resulting list of fields from both `Describe` and `ListFields` is the same -- and all the field names in caps (e.g. `DISTRICTNAME`) are deleted, but still showing up as field names.

`[u'OBJECTID', u'District_Name', u'District_Number', u'LocalOffice_Name', u'Substation_Number', u'FeederID', u'OH_SinglePhase_CircuitMiles', u'OH_TwoPhase_CircuitMiles', u'OH_ThreePhase_CircuitMiles', u'OH_Total_CircuitMiles', u'UG_SinglePhase_CircuitMiles', u'UG_TwoPhase_CircuitMiles', u'UG_ThreePhase_CircuitMiles', u'UG_Total_CircuitMiles', u'UG_TOTALCIR', u'UG_THREEPHASE', u'UG_TWOPHASE', u'UG_SINGLEPHASE', u'OH_TOTALCIR', u'OH_THREEPHASE', u'OH_TWOPHASE', u'OH_SINGLEPHASE', u'CIRCUITID', u'SUBSTATIONID', u'LOCALOFFICENAME', u'DISTRICT', u'DISTRICTNAME']`

`[u'OBJECTID', u'District_Name', u'District_Number', u'LocalOffice_Name', u'Substation_Number', u'FeederID', u'OH_SinglePhase_CircuitMiles', u'OH_TwoPhase_CircuitMiles', u'OH_ThreePhase_CircuitMiles', u'OH_Total_CircuitMiles', u'UG_SinglePhase_CircuitMiles', u'UG_TwoPhase_CircuitMiles', u'UG_ThreePhase_CircuitMiles', u'UG_Total_CircuitMiles', u'UG_TOTALCIR', u'UG_THREEPHASE', u'UG_TWOPHASE', u'UG_SINGLEPHASE', u'OH_TOTALCIR', u'OH_THREEPHASE', u'OH_TWOPHASE', u'OH_SINGLEPHASE', u'CIRCUITID', u'SUBSTATIONID', u'LOCALOFFICENAME', u'DISTRICT', u'DISTRICTNAME']`

Comment: Hey Erica - This is a guess, but perhaps something adverse and schema-lock related is happening between the closing of your `with` statement's frame, and the call to `delete_field()` immediately after it. Have you tried issuing the call to `delete_field()` outside of the `replace_field()` definition in this case? Otherwise, the code reads fine in my opinion, there is no obvious reason why it should not work as-is; in other words, something is happening that is not immediately the script's fault.

Comment: @Jim It's likely some sort of very weird lock. I tried calling `delete_field()` without involving the `replace_field()` function, and ArcPy still sees the "deleted" field...

Comment: That is... such odd behavior for ArcPy and probably outright frustrating for the user. I hope a solution appears soon.

Comment: Yes, it's within another function to which you pass a feature class as `dataset_name`. It would also be called `tbl` except I didn't write it, it's from somebody else's module.

Comment: So one doesn't refer to an in-memory copy, a layer, or anything else? They both refer to the same feature class path/name?

Comment: Correct, both refer to a feature class stored within a gdb. (Although maybe if I make a copy of it before that part...!)

Comment: In that case, I think we need to see more of the code. Does it give the same result if you skip the Describe and do a ListFields()?

Comment: @Tom I've posted an update. It gives the same result.

Comment: how about adding 'del row' before 'delete_field(tbl, oldFieldName)'

Comment: @Björn No effect.

Answer (score 1):

As a *workaround*, copying the "cleaned" feature class to a new feature class before attempting to list fields avoids the issue.